# Does JetBrains Webstorm have a keyboard shortcut for copying the current function?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

In JetBrains Webstorm I would like to have a keyboard shortcut that copies the entirety of the Javascript function my cursor is currently within. Does it support such functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such functionality.

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> might help you though, it selects successively increasing code blocks. That should allow you to use the standard copy and paste shortcuts for copying the function.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use [extend selection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#extend_selection), yes it is not a single shortcut, but im also not aware of this functionality.

you can use this shortcut multiple times until you are happy with the scope of the selection.

[image: gif of function]